# Database Mail Configurations using gmail account

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

After creating a profile and account using gmail account
smtp.gmail.com port 587
I get an error while trying to send a test email

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail
>   server failure. Cannot send mail to mail servers(The SMTP server
>   requires secure connection or the client was not authenticated).

[image]

Command for sending

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'Test Profile',  -- my profile name
    @recipients = 'myaddress@gmail.com',  -- my email address, the same one 
                                          -- which is also configured above
    @body = 'This is a test email sent from TEST server',
    @subject = 'TEST EMAIL',
    @importance ='HIGH'
```

What I am doing wrong? Or should I change some settings from in my gmail account settings?
Thanks

Comment: gmail is tricky, it has some security features in place that will block access if the connection looks fishy to them. If for example you are in a different continent than your server their heuristics could block the connection. I believe you should see that when you visit https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity from your account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your error message says what you have to focus on.
As SSL is enabled make sure to set ON external unsafe application access in gmail setting and not to forget to **refresh** your account. If unsafe access is off, gmail will notify you by a message to assure that it is you trying to access and will show the way how to enable if you click yes.